# Java regex to get the divide a string by '.'

Tags: java, regex

If I have a string `"Sc_bookstore.PKG_book.SP_Harrypotter"`, for example.

How would I separate the schema, package and StoredProc? i.e, I want to get he following output:

```
Sc_bookstore
PKG_book
SP_Harrypotter
```

I am going to be using this regex on multiple StoredProc calls, and all of them follow the standard of "Sc_" "PKG_" "SP_"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer when you're done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want/need Regex, something in the lines of:

```
^(Sc_\w+)\.(PKG_\w+)\.(SP_\w+)$
```

Would allow you to capture the groups values

For input `Sc_bookstore.PKG_book.SP_Harrypotter`:

```
Group 1: "Sc_bookstore"
Group 2: "PKG_book"
Group 3: "SP_Harrypotter"
```

But, in your case, just splitting the String by `.` would suit your needs very well

Answer (score 5):

Use `"\\."` or `"[.]"` if a regular expression split delimiter is required (as with [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))).

A `.` in a [Java regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) means "match any character" (roughly, depending on options); the two forms above escape/prevent this meaning so it matches a literal period.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you need to divide a string by a delimeter, you should consider using the String `split` method:

```
String s = "Sc_bookstore.PKG_book.SP_Harrypotter";
String parts[] = s.split("\\.");
parts[0]; // holds "Sc_bookstore"
parts[1]; // holds "PKG_book"
parts[2]; // holds "SP_Harrypotter"
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked too. But I had to use the full regex to make sure I am only getting the once with Sc schema etc.

Comment: Sorry. Never posted here before. I'll make sure it's clearer next time.

Answer (score 0):

you may use split (with no regex)

```
String[] values;
values = str.split("\\.");
```

Comment: Your regex is wrong. A single . will match any character you need to pass in a \ for it to be a litteral you also need to escape the slash so it ends up being \\.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a single string always contains exactly one such record, use this:

```
^Sc_([^.]+)\.PKG_([^.]+)\.SP_([^$]+)$
```

...note that this removes the Sc_, PKG_ and SP_ parts of the string and only returns "content".

For testing purposes, I created a simple [JavaRegexTester](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaregextester/) application to test regular expressions.